# Firefox javascript error

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am having the following error viewing validation error in Firefox, it works in Chrome and Safari.

This is the original code:

```
function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
  if (document.getElementById){
    var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
    for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
      if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
        if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
          if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
        } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
          if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a valid number no spaces.\n';
          if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
            min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
            if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
      } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
    } if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
    document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
} }
```

This is my new javascript code to send the error message to a div with id fterror;

```
function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
  if (document.getElementById){
    var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
    for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
      if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
        if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
          if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+=' '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
        } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
          if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a valid number no spaces.\n';
          if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
            min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
            if (num<min || max<num) errors+=' '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
      } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += ' '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
    } if (errors) document.getElementById('fterror').innerText = "Please correct the following error(s): \n"+errors;
    document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
    if (errors == '') document.getElementById('fterror').innerText = "";
} }
```

Comment: That is one seriously messed up piece of code. Any chance you can just use Dreamweaver to setup your new rules again?

If not, you should try to pinpoint the exact difference in the script and then it's easier to help out.

Comment: Please format your code, provide a "working" example that illustrates the error, precisely describe what you expect and what actually happens. Also, without seeing the call or associated HTML, you are expecting those who might wish to help you to have a crystal ball. As far as I can tell, the only difference between the two bits of code is the hyphen in the following: `errors+='- '+nm+'`. I don't think that will have any significant effect on the outcome of running this code other than the obvious insertion of a hyphen in the string.

Comment: Thanks for your response Pal,  The only change is the 3 lines of code. the error message is displayed in an alert box but i would like to write the error to a div tag.

Comment: Hi RobG,  error+='- ' only adds a - to the front of the error message.

Comment: the only change is the bottom 3 lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` for it to work in Firefox:

```
document.getElementById('fterror').innerHTML = ...
```

Comment: I have changed as requested and all is working, thanks very much for your help :)))